# Passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to make a simple procfs module, but I get this error:

```
error: passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
```

I tried many online examples and i got same error message.

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk https://gist.github.com/BrotherJing/c9c5ffdc9954d998d1336711fa3a6480

Comment: I use 5.6.3 kernel

Comment: You have to use `proc_ops` in newer kernels instead of `file_operations`. See commit `d56c0d45f0e27f814e87a1676b6bdccccbc252e9`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Thank you )

Comment: Well, actually in the given case the error message is mostly sufficient to find and resolve the problem. Voted for reopen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `proc_ops` in newer kernels instead of `file_operations`, see https://lore.kernel.org/linux-fsdevel/20191225172228.GA13378@avx2/:

```
static struct proc_ops my_fops={
    .proc_open = my_proc_open,
    .proc_release = single_release,
    .proc_read = seq_read,
    .proc_lseek = seq_lseek,
    .proc_write = my_proc_write
};
```