# What To Do With cdev_init When Converting file_operations To proc_ops?

Tags: linux-kernel

According to this question [Passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create’ from incompatible pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295277/passing-argument-4-of-proc-create-from-incompatible-pointer-type)

You have to use `proc_ops` instead of `file_operations` structs on newer kernels.

How should we handle initializing the cdev with `cdev_init` when it uses the old `file_operations` structs?

I have looked through some examples on newer linux kernels (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/char/pcmcia/scr24x_cs.c#L216) but they still use the old `file_operations`.

Thanks,
-Special K

Comment: `proc_create` creates a **file** under **proc** filesystem. `cdev_init` initializes a **character device**. These are two separated things, and changing interface for one doesn't imply changing interface for another. The link to the example just confirms, that `cdev_init` interface hasn't been changed.

Comment: I don't understand.  Doesn't `proc_ops` replace `file_operations` on the newer kernels?

Comment: "Doesn't `proc_ops` replace `file_operations` on the newer kernels?" - No, `file_operations` remains in the new kernels. They are replaced by `proc_ops` only for files under proc filesystem, thus affecting `proc_create` function.

Comment: "No, file_operations remains in the new kernels. They are replaced by proc_ops only for files under proc filesystem, thus affecting proc_create function"  Oh, you are right.  Sorry, I was looking at the wrong struct.  I actually have a different issue than what I thought.  Thank you.  How do I accept your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signature of `cdev_init()` function [still uses](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.5/source/fs/char_dev.c#L651) argument pointed to `struct file_operations` object, so you needn't to change this call when adapt your module for newer kernels.

Signature for `proc_create()` function has been changed because it works with files under **proc filesystem (procfs)**, and this filesystem has been re-designed in the newer kernels.

`cdev_init` function creates (initializes) a *character device*. While character devices are usually represented by a file (which could also be located under procfs), this file is of special type, and operations of this files are not the same as operations of character device itself. Because `cdev_init` is only responsible for character device (not a file), it is unaffected by changings in procfs design.