# How to fix error: passing argument 4 of 'proc_create' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to load things to my kernel to learn about how you can add things!

I have two files here!

Below is skynet.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros

#include <linux/proc_fs.h>   // file operations
#include <linux/seq_file.h>  // seq_read, ...

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Dr. Dyson");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Global Information Grid");

static int skynet_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v);

static int skynet_open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file);

static const struct file_operations skynet_fops = {
  .owner = THIS_MODULE,
  .open = skynet_open,
  .read = seq_read,
  .llseek = seq_lseek,
  .release = single_release,
};


static int skynet_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v) {
 here:
  seq_printf(m, "Skynet location: 0x%lx\n", (unsigned long)&&here);
  return 0;
}

static int skynet_open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file) {
  return single_open(file, skynet_show, NULL);
}


static int __init skynet_init(void) {
  proc_create("skynet", 0, NULL, &skynet_fops);
  printk(KERN_INFO "Skynet in control\n");

  return 0;
}

static void __exit skynet_cleanup(void) {
  remove_proc_entry("skynet", NULL);
  printk(KERN_INFO "I'll be back!\n");
}

module_init(skynet_init);
module_exit(skynet_cleanup);
```

Below here is the Makefile:

obj-m += skynet.o

all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

But when i write in make i get this error in the terminal below:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.8.0-29-generic/build M=/home/jonteyh/ID1200/Device/skynet modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-29-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/jonteyh/ID1200/Device/skynet/skynet.o
/home/jonteyh/ID1200/Device/skynet/skynet.c: In function ‘skynet_init’:
/home/jonteyh/ID1200/Device/skynet/skynet.c:37:34: error: passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   37 |   proc_create("skynet", 0, NULL, &skynet_fops);
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                  |
      |                                  const struct file_operations *
In file included from /home/jonteyh/ID1200/Device/skynet/skynet.c:5:
./include/linux/proc_fs.h:107:122: note: expected ‘const struct proc_ops *’ but argument is of type ‘const struct file_operations *’
  107 | struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create(const char *name, umode_t mode, struct proc_dir_entry *parent, const struct proc_ops *proc_ops);
      |                                                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:290: /home/jonteyh/ID1200/Device/skynet/skynet.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1780: /home/jonteyh/ID1200/Device/skynet] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-29-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

What i have tried is to change is file_operations to proc_ops the things below:

```
static const struct proc_ops skynet_fops = {
  .owner = THIS_MODULE,
  .open = skynet_open,
  .read = seq_read,
  .llseek = seq_lseek,
  .release = single_release,
};
```

But then i got other errors such like release dosen't exist.
How can i solve this error incompatible??

Comment: Why are you using file_ops?  Here is struct proc_ops: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/proc_fs.h#L29

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing argument 4 of ‘proc\_create’ from incompatible pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295277/passing-argument-4-of-proc-create-from-incompatible-pointer-type)

Comment: Tsyvarev i have tried that and that didn't help!

Comment: Tsyvarev i have tried that didn't you read what i had tried?

Comment: @stark Because it said on a older post on Stackoverflow that it would solve the problem?

Comment: Then use the older kernel that it was referring to.

Comment: @stark can you switch to a older kernel?

Comment: "i have tried that didn't you read what i had tried?" - Comparing to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295277/passing-argument-4-of-proc-create-from-incompatible-pointer-type) to the referenced question, you have tried to change the type of the structure (from `struct file_operations` to `struct proc_ops`) but forgot to change names of the methods too (e.g. change `.release` to `.proc_release`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two solutions.

The first solution is to replace `struct file_operations` with `struct proc_ops` for kernel version 5.6 or later:

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros

#include <linux/proc_fs.h>   // file operations
#include <linux/seq_file.h>  // seq_read, ...

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Dr. Dyson");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Global Information Grid");

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(5,6,0)
#define HAVE_PROC_OPS
#endif

static int skynet_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v);

static int skynet_open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file);

#ifdef HAVE_PROC_OPS
static const struct proc_ops skynet_ops = {
  .proc_open = skynet_open,
  .proc_read = seq_read,
  .proc_lseek = seq_lseek,
  .proc_release = single_release,
};
#else
static const struct file_operations skynet_ops = {
  .owner = THIS_MODULE,
  .open = skynet_open,
  .read = seq_read,
  .llseek = seq_lseek,
  .release = single_release,
};
#endif


static int skynet_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v) {
 here:
  seq_printf(m, "Skynet location: 0x%lx\n", (unsigned long)&&here);
  return 0;
}

static int skynet_open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file) {
  return single_open(file, skynet_show, NULL);
}


static int __init skynet_init(void) {
  proc_create("skynet", 0, NULL, &skynet_ops);
  printk(KERN_INFO "Skynet in control\n");

  return 0;
}

static void __exit skynet_cleanup(void) {
  remove_proc_entry("skynet", NULL);
  printk(KERN_INFO "I'll be back!\n");
}

module_init(skynet_init);
module_exit(skynet_cleanup);
```

The second solution is to replace `proc_create` with `proc_create_single` for kernel version 4.18 or later when all that is required is a basic, read-only proc file:

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
#include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros

#include <linux/proc_fs.h>   // file operations
#include <linux/seq_file.h>  // seq_read, ...

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Dr. Dyson");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Global Information Grid");

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4,18,0)
#define HAVE_PROC_CREATE_SINGLE
#endif


static int skynet_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v) {
 here:
  seq_printf(m, "Skynet location: 0x%lx\n", (unsigned long)&&here);
  return 0;
}

#ifndef HAVE_PROC_CREATE_SINGLE
static int skynet_open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file) {
  return single_open(file, skynet_show, NULL);
}

static const struct file_operations skynet_fops = {
  .owner = THIS_MODULE,
  .open = skynet_open,
  .read = seq_read,
  .llseek = seq_lseek,
  .release = single_release,
};
#endif


static int __init skynet_init(void) {
#ifdef HAVE_PROC_CREATE_SINGLE
  proc_create_single("skynet", 0, NULL, skynet_show);
#else
  proc_create("skynet", 0, NULL, &skynet_fops);
#endif
  printk(KERN_INFO "Skynet in control\n");

  return 0;
}

static void __exit skynet_cleanup(void) {
  remove_proc_entry("skynet", NULL);
  printk(KERN_INFO "I'll be back!\n");
}

module_init(skynet_init);
module_exit(skynet_cleanup);
```